# Execute program each time somebody logs in via SSH into a Linux box

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a small SSH server, and I'd like to write a script to run each time somebody logs in via SSH.

Now, how would I go about that?

I'd like the script to run everytime ANYBODY logs in, and I need to have access to at least the username of the person who logged in, and the IP address the person logged in from.

I thought about using `/etc/bash.bashrc`, but is that a good solution? For instance, is there a way a user could disable its use, and thus disable my script? If yes, what are my other options?

Thanks.

Comment: This will only work if the user uses bash, of course. It will not work if the users can select their own shell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The mechanism to use depends upon your goals.

If you wish to provide something *convenient* or *friendly* for your users, then your `/etc/profile` is reasonable enough if all your users use the same shell. If you want the commands to execute *only* when logging in via `ssh`, place commands into `/etc/ssh/sshrc`. (If you don't mind users overriding the commands with their own `~/.ssh/rc` file.)

If you want to *force* a user to execute one program, *and only one program*, then the `ForceCommand` option as described by DigitalRoss is a good approach. (I personally would further confine the user with a [mandatory access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) system such as [AppArmor](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor/), [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux), [TOMOYO](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en), or [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/), to ensure the program can not allow a user to escape. I've worked on AppArmor for ten years, so that's the tool I'd pick first, but the others are fine tools written by excellent programmers.)

If you just want one program to execute *and not bother the user in any way*, then the best approach is to use the `pam_exec(8)` module, which cannot be bypassed, works regardless of shell, and provides easy ability to run as the user or as the user account of the program performing the authorization. The manpage gives the following example:

```
   Add the following line to /etc/pam.d/passwd to rebuild the
   NIS database after each local password change:

               passwd optional pam_exec.so seteuid make -C /var/yp

   This will execute the command

       make -C /var/yp

   with effective user ID.
```

This could be extended to run on `auth`, `account`, `password`, and `session` actions; probably `session` would be best for executing upon log in. Just add a line like:

```
session optional pam_exec.so log=/var/log/ssh_login_cmd /usr/local/bin/ssh_cmd
```

to your `/etc/pam.d/sshd` control file.

Comment: Looks like the `pam_exec` module is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: WATCH OUT, if the command you exec exits with a non zero exit code your login will fail and you could be locked out. One way to solve this is to make sure there is another 'session optional' called with a different module that always succeeds.

Answer (score 4):

Newish versions of OpenSSH have a server feature called *ForceCommand* that gives control to a script instead of the operation (scp, ssh, ...) that the user intended. The script is passed the original command, so you could probably chain to it after doing whatever you need to do.

From sshd_config(5):

> **ForceCommand**
>
> Forces the execution of the command
>   specified by ForceCommand, ignoring
>   any command supplied by the client and
>   ~/.ssh/rc if present.  The command is
>   invoked by using the user's login
>   shell with the -c option.  This
>   applies to shell, command, or
>   subsystem execution.  It is most
>   useful inside a Match block.  The
>   command originally supplied by the
>   client is available in the
>   SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment vari-
>   able.  Specifying a command of
>   ``internal-sftp'' will force the use
>   of an in-process sftp server that
>   requires no support files when used
>   with ChrootDirectory.

I used this once to override scp and provide secure gem upload without giving every user authorized to upload gems interactive access they didn't need or want.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use [syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/network-security/syslog-ng/opensource-logging-system) as a syslog daemon and configure it to run a script background every time a certain log entry (such as a successful ssh login) matches.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9383927

I don't believe there is a way to disable this from running. Can anyone else verify this?

Comment: It (`/etc/profile` or `~/.profile`) depends on the shell of the user, just a bit less than `bashrc`. If your users are using a bash or similar, this is fine.